Proof that $f(x) = \frac{xa^{x-1}(1-a)}{1-a^{x}}<1$ for $x>1$.
I have a problem. This problem seems easy, but after I try, I feel this is hard.
Let $a \in (0,1)$, let $f(x) = \frac{xa^{x-1}(1-a)}{1-a^{x}}$. Proof for $x>1$, $f(x) < 1$.
I already draw the graph and this is true. I also had try to proof this using standard algebra, but I can't proof this. Maybe I must use some real analysis tools. Please help me, sorry and thank you very much.

Have you been taught to explore the behavior of a function $~f(x)~$ by examining its derivative?

Thank you, I will try to proof that $f$ strictly dec., because $f(1)$ is 1.

I have proof using first derivative, but it is long. Do you have another way to prove this.

No, I haven't looked at the problem.  I suggest that you edit your posted question to include your proof.

Standard way: In order to prove that $f(x)=\frac{xa^{x-1}(1-a)}{1-a^x}<1, \forall x\in (1,\infty)$, it is equivalent to proving that $xa^{x-1}(1-a)<1-a^x, \forall x\in(1,\infty)$. Define $g(x)=-xa^{x-1}(1-a)+1-a^x$, then \begin{align*}g'(x)&=-x(1-a)a^{x-1}\ln a-a^{x-1}(1-a)-a^x\ln a  \\ & =-a^{x-1}\underbrace{[a\ln a+x(1-a)\ln a+(1-a)]}_{h(x)}.\end{align*}
$$h'(x)=(1-a)\ln a>0\implies h(x)\ \text{is nonincreasing}.$$
Notice that $g(1)=0$. If we can prove that $g'(x)> 0, \forall x\in (1,\infty)$, then we are done. To prove this, we need to show that $h(x)<0, \forall x>1$. Only need to verify that $h(1)< 0$. $$h(1)=a\ln a+\ln a-a\ln a+1-a=\ln a+1-a.$$
Since $\ln x< x-1,\forall x\in (0,1)$, $h(1)< 0$  and we are done.

You can use Bernoulli inequality for real exponents as follows:
First, rearrange the given inequality:
$$f(x) = \frac{xa^{x-1}(1-a)}{1-a^{x}}=x\frac{1-a}{a}\frac{a^x}{1-a^x}< 1 \Leftrightarrow x\left(\frac 1a-1\right)< \frac 1{a^x}-1$$
Now, set $\boxed{\frac 1a = 1+p}$ with $p>0$:
$$x\left(\frac 1a-1\right)< \frac 1{a^x}-1\stackrel{\frac 1a = 1+p}{\Leftrightarrow}\underbrace{xp < (1+p)^x -1}_{\text{This is Bernoulli}}$$

$1-\frac 1a$ should be $\frac 1a-1$.

Exactly. Adjusted. Thank you.
